# Windows how to emulate an internal display in a virtual machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, .net-framework, wmi

I'm trying to run a program in a virtual machine, this program try to fetch my display information trought Windows WMI with a query:

```
var success = true;

List<Display> displays = new List<Display>();

// Query WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams to retrieve display parameters
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Root\WMI", "SELECT * FROM 
WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams"))

using (var results = searcher.Get())
```

for some reason Windows WMI fail to fetch the display information of my virtual display and the program crash throwing this exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Management.ManagementException: Not supported
at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
```

this happen in EVERY virtual machine, and the display is always classified as a NON PnP device.

So how do i emulate a real internal display? (like a laptop display) so that Windows WMI doesn't make crash the program? Otherwise is there a way to intercept and modify the result of a WMI query and then return it to the program c# code?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Machine Apps (VMware, Virtual Box, Hyper-V) create virtual hardware (not real hardware) for the guest machines to use.

> So how do i emulate a real internal display? (like a laptop display)
> so that Windows WMI doesn't make crash the program? Otherwise is there
> a way to intercept and modify the result of a WMI query and then
> return it to the program c# code?

You cannot (as per my first comment).  What you are trying to do cannot work in a virtual machine.

I use both VMware and Hyper-V

You need a real (physical) machine to run and test your program.

Comment: It's not mine, this app is coded in this way and i cannot change the way it's done, so if is impossible to make Windows belive that there is an internal display where there isn't,  Is there not a way to intercept the result of that WMI query and change it?

Comment: No, I do not think so. WMI is expecting real hardware and the emulated hardware does not do what you want.

Comment: If i need the hardware, the only things that comes to mind is dummy display plug. Is there a dummy display plug (a usb key that simulate a fake monitor) but that is releaved as internal and non as an external display?

Comment: I have not see such a thing for a virtual machine.  VMs usually allow USB pass through but the dummy plug is not the same thing.